# How can I show this function is bounded?

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $p>1$ and define $F_p:(-1,1)\times (-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$F_p(a,b)=\frac{1}{|a|}\int_{-1+b}^{1+b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}}^{p+1}}dx$$

I would like to show that this function satisfies for for fixed $p$ $$c_1\leq F_p(a,b)\leq c_2$$

where $c_1>0$ and $c_1,c_2$ may depend on $p$. I tried some cases in Mathematica with positive answer, however, until now I was not successful in foind such bounds. The integral can be transformed in something like $\int (\sec{x})^{2-p-1}dx$ and from here I am stuck.

Any help is aprecciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $t:=\frac x{|a|}$ to get 
$$F_p(a,b)=\int_{\frac{-1+b}{|a|}}^{\frac{1+b}{|a|}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{p+1}2}}.$$
This is certainly smaller than $\int_{—\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dt}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{p+1}2}}$, a convergent integral.

Sine the integrand is even and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$, we get 
$$F_p(a,b)\geqslant 2\int_0^{\frac{2}{|a|}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{p+1}2}}\geqslant 2\int_0^2\frac{\mathrm dt}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{p+1}2}}.$$